# How to convert excel in API side?

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio, angular6

As question, How to convert excel in API and transfer as file back to the service?
Currently I able to get the data from database already but after getting the data from it, I'm not sure how to convert the data to excel before send back to the service. I need to convert it in api instead of in angular component side after getting the full completed of data from API.

```
    [Route("getExcelData")]
    [Authenticate]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult GetExcelData([FromBody]Report obj)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Contents.Add("Result", new ReportService().getExcelData(obj.Id, obj.FromDate, obj.ToDate));
            return JsonResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogManager.Instance.InsertLog(LogLevel.Error, e.Message, e.StackTrace, "ReportController", "ReportController", null, null);
            ExceptionManager.Instance.Add(String.Format("GetData Failed: {0}", e.Message), $"{e.StackTrace} Inner Exception: {e.InnerException}");
            this.Contents.Add("Result", null);
            return JsonResponse();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code worked for me.

> please find more elobarations [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/6-easy-ways-to-export-data-to-excel-in-c-sharp.aspx#DataTable-to-Excel).

```
#region Loading the data to DataGridView
DataSet customersDataSet = new DataSet();

//Read the XML file with data
string inputXmlPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"../../Data/Employees.xml");
customersDataSet.ReadXml(inputXmlPath);
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

//Copy the structure and data of the table
dataTable = customersDataSet.Tables[1].Copy();

//Removing unwanted columns
dataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
dataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(10);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9F, ((System.Drawing.FontStyle)(System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)));
dataGridView1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
dataGridView1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
#endregion

using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
{
    IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;

    //Create a workbook with single worksheet
    IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Create(1);

    IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

    //Import from DataGridView to worksheet
    worksheet.ImportDataGridView(dataGridView1, 1, 1, isImportHeader: true, isImportStyle: true);

    worksheet.UsedRange.AutofitColumns();
    workbook.SaveAs("Output.xlsx");
}
```

Comment: How should I implement it in my code? Sorry for distrub because I really dont know how to make it.

Comment: Get data first fetched into your API from DB as a table and cast it according to XML. then pass it to the `Path.GetFullPath`